# why isn't my custom view showing up in simulator

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, uibezierpath

This is my first time dealing with custom views (so execuse my ignorance) and so I'm trying to figure out whether this should work (or why it doesn't). I have tried to create a custom view (called IAMax) by doing New -> File and setting the parent to UIView. I removed the initWithFrame and add the following to drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    NSLog(@"here i am");
    UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0, 0.0)];
    // Draw the lines.
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(200.0, 40.0)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(160, 140)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(40.0, 140)];
    [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 40.0)];
    [aPath closePath];
}
```

I go to my main storyboard and drag out a generic UIView to my main storyboard and switch the Class to IAMax (and switch the background color to green). When I run in the simulator, I don't see anything (but I do see the NSLog statement in the console). What am I doing wrong?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creating the path you need to draw it:

```
[[UIColor redColor] set];
[aPath stroke];
```

This will draw the path in red.

Comment: ahh, thank you so much! I thought I was doing something wrong in the UIView - have to wait a few minutes.